# How to explain constant freezings in a game ASSUMING hardware specs are ok?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, pubg-battlegrounds

I have constant freezings in a game (PUBG). Approximately each second (non uniformly) any animation stops for a few instants then goes further. It happens even in splash screen animation.

What can cause this, assuming my hardware specs are ok?

Please suggest software or assembling hints.

I have Windows 10 64 bit, 32 GB RAM
CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K
GPU Geforce GTX 1070 8 Gb

When I ran Geforce Experience optimiser, it sets game to maximal resolution and effects.

I suspect some configuration issues, for example, multiple monitors.

What is the correct name of this problem? Maybe shuttering?

How to get more diagnostics?

I have latest drivers. I tried to set lower resolution.

Comment: I would call this "stuttering".  It could probably happen for a number of reasons.  Do you have an anti-virus software running and scanning files? Do you have sufficient power (i.e. not running in a power saving mode?)  Is anything overheating (GPU, CPU?)

Comment: Nothing is overheating according to `Open Hardware Monitor`, Avast antivirus is apparently disabled, no power saving.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many causes of stuttering, even with good hardware. I will go over some of the most common causes.

**Power-Saving Features**:
You want to disable all power saving features in the BIOS, within Windows, and within the GPU driver. You can do this by disabling C-States in the BIOS, locking the CPU clock speed to its maximum and using a constant voltage in the BIOS, setting Windows to the maximum power plan, setting the GPU to "prefer maximum performance" in the NVIDIA Control Panel, and using MSI Afterburner to lock GPU clock speeds to their maximum at all times.

**Background Programs**:
Check your startup programs. Disable anything you don't use/need. Check the services running in the background. Terminate as many as you can and change them to "manual" mode to prevent them from automatically starting. Some of the absolute worst offenders are any RGB software, monitoring software, and antivirus programs. You can also enable game mode on your PC to see if that helps.

**Other Poor Settings**:
Try to use hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling. Make sure your game is running at lower settings. I would never recommend using the NVIDIA optimizer like you have used. Disable that and manually set your settings to your native resolution and much lower. For reference, I play games at low/medium settings for maximum FPS and smoothness even on my i9 13900K and RTX 4090.

**Hardware is not as good as you think it is**:
The i7 4770K and GTX 1070 are not bad parts necessarily, but they are definitely very weak heading into 2023. My guess is that your CPU is simply not powerful enough for a smooth experience in a large battle royale game with its low clock speeds and instructions per clock. Also, how is your RAM configured? Slow DDR3 is not doing you any favors in terms of getting a smooth experience.